# nunit 3.0 subscription to post creating result file event

Tags: c#, nunit

I am extending the nunit framework and need to subscribe to an event that is triggered after TestResult.xml file has already been written.
Is there such thing? 
How can I do it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is not.

There are some good reasons for this:

1. An output XML file is not always produced.
2. When it is produced, it is not always produced in nunit3 format, but sometimes in other formats - even user-defined.

What you can count on is that an in-memory structure of the entire result will be made available as XML to any Output Writer extension you create. Additionally, individual results of each test are made available to any Event Listener extensions.